# How to overide GPU time given to Windows XP or applications?

Tags: windows-xp, gpu

I have an application that uses the [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) (I am not sure if it's [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)). This application has an intensity control; if it is set too high, the more productive is, but Windows itself and every application (all applications need the GPU for drawing the window at least) are getting non-responsive. It took me half an hour to:

- Go my mouse pointer to the [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) usage in the tray (mouse poiner move is jerky too),
- To get to accept two clicks for a double-click
- To get the main window drawn
- To get the processes shown
- To get the mouse select the application to terminate it
- To get the confirmation window
- To get a single click in yes!

This is not joke, this whole thing that normally takes 1-2 seconds took me about half an hour!

So is there a way that I can overide the time that Windows or the application takes, because I don't want to reduce the intensity?

This is the application's fault, because other OpenCL applications use the GPU @100%, but let you do everything else right; you can move windows/folders without any delay and the only drawback is that when you do that the performance ot that application drops a bit until you stop doing anything that "distracts" the GPU's "attention".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess.. you're [mining for coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_protocol#Bitcoin_mining)?

The only thing you really can do is to lower the intensity. Just lowering it a little bit shouldn't matter much on your hash rate, but it should make your machine a lot more responsive.

You say you don't want to lower the intensity... but if you were to find a program that would force the GPU to spend more time on updating your mouse and windows, instead of spending time on your application, the result would be the exact same thing.

No matter what you do you'll never get to a point where the machine still has a good hash rate and still can be used normally while mining. You can't have both at the same time...

Unless if you plug in an extra (cheap crappy) graphics card, and then use that one for drawing mouse/windows/surfing.

Comment: Found me! Haha! Yes, its the gpuminer/scrypt (litecoin), but this can happen with many games or apps and freeze your computer, thats why I didn't got in details.

Well as for bitcoins, the opencl miner acts just right; using a flag -f can set the priority, so you loose hash-rate only when you move folders/windows or use the gpu for something else!